# How to force open an excel file from a Sharepoint location in the browser, via a hyperlink?

Tags: sharepoint, hyperlink, xlsx

I am not sure if this is the right place for this question.
But I try anyway.

I want to be able to open a document via a dynamic hyperlink in excel.

In an Excel file I have 1 fixed cell that always contains a different article number after it has been selected from a list.
Then I want to open another Excel file via a link, which is located in a fixed folder.
This folder contains several Excel files.
Each Excel file has the same value as the value in the fixed cell can have. The name therefore corresponds to the article number followed by .xlsx.

Example:
in the fixed cell I select: 123456 (The length of the item number can be longer or shorter)
I then want to open the Excel file 123456.xlsx, via the link I created, in the browser.
The file to open is located in a Sharepoint folder.

I have it partially working.
But the file is being downloaded instead of opened in the browser.
How can I force it to open the file in the browser?

What I have now is this:

```
=HYPERLINK("file:"&N3&H9&N1;"TEXT")  
where:  
N3= the link to the folder on Sharepoint  
H9= 123456 (article number)  
N1= .xlsx  
TEXT= the text which I have stated in K6, on which one need to click to go to the specific file.
```

I hope that someone has experience with this.

Thanks!

BR, Nanno

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding **?web=1** to the end of your link.

Reference:[Open a Document in Browser instead of Client Application in SharePoint Online](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/12/open-document-in-browser-instead-of-client-application-in-sharepoint-online.html)

Comment: It seems that the excel webversion works differently than the App version. I had to Concatenate the string and link the hyperlink to this concatenated cell.